# How to connect Spring to Oracle Database using eclipse IDE.

Tags: database, spring, oracle, spring-mvc

I couldn't connect the spring application with oracle db (12c). I have installed the jdbc8 (java to oracle driver) locally and installed all the spring and jdbc dependencies.

Can anyone please help me with it. I'm unable to run the application (access and update the database ). maven build was successful and compilation was sucessful.

Steps I followed to run the application: 
1) build as maven clean. 
2) run the application. (not on apache)

****console log: 
Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 JDBC 4.2 compiled with javac 1.8.0_91
***** JCE UNLIMITED STRENGTH IS INSTALLED ********

Code for contact.java

```
package net.codejava.spring;

 /**
 * 
 * @author www.codejava.net
  *
   */
    public class Contact {
    private String name;
    private String email;
    private String address;
    private String phone;

    public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getAddress() {
    return address;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String telephone) {
    this.phone = telephone;
}

public String toString() {
    return String.format("[%s - %s - %s - %s]", name, email, address, phone);
}
```

}

code for SpringJDBCTemplateExmaple.java

```
    package net.codejava.spring;

    import java.sql.ResultSet;
    import java.sql.SQLException;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper;
    import org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource;

     /**
    * This console application demonstrates how to do CRUD operations using              JDBC
    * with Spring framework.
    * @author www.codejava.net
     *
     */
    public class SpringJDBCTemplateExample {

public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
    SimpleDriverDataSource dataSource = new SimpleDriverDataSource();
    dataSource.setDriver(new oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver());
    dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL");
    dataSource.setUsername("system");
    dataSource.setPassword("Welcome1");

    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    String sqlInsert = "INSERT INTO contact (name, email, address, telephone)"
            + " VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sqlInsert, "Tom", "tomea@mail.com", "USA", "12345");

    String sqlUpdate = "UPDATE contact set email=? where name=?";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sqlUpdate, "tomee@mail.com", "Tom");

    String sqlSelect = "SELECT * FROM contact";
    List<Contact> listContact = jdbcTemplate.query(sqlSelect, new RowMapper<Contact>() {

        public Contact mapRow(ResultSet result, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Contact contact = new Contact();
            contact.setName(result.getString("name"));
            contact.setEmail(result.getString("email"));
            contact.setAddress(result.getString("address"));
            contact.setPhone(result.getString("telephone"));

            return contact;
        }

    });

    for (Contact aContact : listContact) {
        System.out.println(aContact);
    }

    String sqlDelete = "DELETE FROM contact1 where name=?";
    jdbcTemplate.update(sqlDelete, "Tom");
}
```

}

code for pom.xml

```
       <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>net.codejava.spring</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringJDBCTemplateExample</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<name>SpringJDBCTemplateExample</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc8</artifactId>
        <version>12.1.0.1</version>     
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

contact table:

```
         CREATE TABLE contact (
           contact_id integer NOT NULL,
           name varchar(45) NOT NULL,
           email varchar(45) NOT NULL,
           address varchar(45) NOT NULL,
           telephone varchar(45) NOT NULL,
           CONSTRAINT contact_pk PRIMARY KEY (contact_id)
            );
```

Comment: "I'm unable to run the application" is not very helpful.  Please post error details.

Comment: ****console log: Oracle 12.2.0.1.0 JDBC 4.2 compiled with javac 1.8.0_91 ***** JCE UNLIMITED STRENGTH IS INSTALLED ********           

There were no compilation errors. I'm not sure if I'm following the right steps to run the application.

Comment: **There were no compilation errors. I'm not sure if I'm following the right steps to connect my application to the oracle db.

Comment: I meant when you run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in your SpringJDBCTemplateExample main method looks correct & should work provided all the parameters are correct for your setup, e.g.

```
dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:ORCL");
dataSource.setUsername("system");
dataSource.setPassword("Welcome1");
```

So if you do have an Oracle database with SID or service name "ORCL" listening on your local port 1521, and there is a "system" user with password "Welcome1" then the JdbcTemplate should be able to use that DataSource to connect.

If the connection fails, an exception would be thrown and you should see a stacktrace output which will tell you what is wrong.  For example, if the password was wrong, you should see something like: -

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.jdbc.CannotGetJdbcConnectionException: Could not get JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:630)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:909)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:970)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.update(JdbcTemplate.java:980)
    ...
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

Now ... if you are running your SpringJDBCTemplateExample and you don't see any output from your program, then I would think you have something either wrong with the logging setup or the standard output is being redirected somewhere.